# Jersey not mapping response to JAVA Object

Tags: java, web-services, jersey, pojo, wildfly-10

I am trying to consume Google Time Zone API Response. I have tried all answers on Stack Overflow related to this error but the below error is not even changing a bit:

```
ERROR [ClientResponse]:625 - A message body reader for Java class com.bystored.business.bo.timezone.TimeZoneResponse, and Java type class com.bystored.business.bo.timezone.TimeZoneResponse, and MIME media type application/json; charset=UTF-8 was not found
2016-10-12 14:39:36 ERROR [ClientResponse]:627 - The registered message body readers compatible with the MIME media type are:
application/json; charset=UTF-8 ->
com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONJAXBElementProvider$App
com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONArrayProvider$App
com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONObjectProvider$App
com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONRootElementProvider$App
com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONListElementProvider$App
*/* ->
com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FormProvider
com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.MimeMultipartProvider
com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StringProvider
com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ByteArrayProvider
com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FileProvider
com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.InputStreamProvider
com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DataSourceProvider
com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLJAXBElementProvider$General
com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ReaderProvider
com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DocumentProvider
com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$StreamSourceReader
com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$SAXSourceReader
com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$DOMSourceReader
com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONJAXBElementProvider$General
com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONArrayProvider$General
com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONObjectProvider$General
com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootElementProvider$General
com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLListElementProvider$General
com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootObjectProvider$General
com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.EntityHolderReader
com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONRootElementProvider$General
com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JSONListElementProvider$General
com.sun.jersey.json.impl.provider.entity.JacksonProviderProxy
```

Below is my JAVA class:

```
public class TimeZoneResponse implements Serializable {
private long dstOffset;
private long rawOffset;
private String status;
private String timeZoneId;
private String timeZoneName;

@JsonProperty("dstOffset")
public long getDstOffset() {
    return dstOffset;
}

public void setDstOffset(long dstOffset) {
    this.dstOffset = dstOffset;
}

@JsonProperty("rawOffset")
public long getRawOffset() {
    return rawOffset;
}

public void setRawOffset(long rawOffset) {
    this.rawOffset = rawOffset;
}

@JsonProperty("status")
public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}

@JsonProperty("timeZoneId")
public String getTimeZoneId() {
    return timeZoneId;
}

public void setTimeZoneId(String timeZoneId) {
    this.timeZoneId = timeZoneId;
}

@JsonProperty("timeZoneName")
public String getTimeZoneName() {
    return timeZoneName;
}

public void setTimeZoneName(String timeZoneName) {
    this.timeZoneName = timeZoneName;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "TimeZoneResponse{" +
            "dstOffset=" + dstOffset +
            ", rawOffset=" + rawOffset +
            ", status='" + status + '\'' +
            ", timeZoneId='" + timeZoneId + '\'' +
            ", timeZoneName='" + timeZoneName + '\'' +
            '}';
}
}
```

Jersey Client GET method is below:

```
public static <T extends Object> T get (String url, Map<String, String> queryParams, Map<String, String> headers, Class<? extends T> type) {
    Client client = Client.create();
    WebResource webResource = client.resource(url);

    if (queryParams != null) {
        for (String key : queryParams.keySet()) {
            webResource = webResource.queryParam(key, queryParams.get(key));
        }
    }

    WebResource.Builder builder = webResource.getRequestBuilder();
    if(headers != null && !headers.isEmpty()) {
        for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : headers.entrySet()) {
            builder = webResource.header(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
        }
    }

    return builder.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(type);

}
```

I have dependencies of `jersey-server` `jersey-bundle` `jersey-json` in `pom`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like you configure the `POJOMappingFeature` on the server, you need to also configure it on the client

```
ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
config.getFeatures().put(JSONConfiguration.FEATURE_POJO_MAPPING, true);
Client client = Client.create(config);
```

It's been a while since I used Jersey 1, so if the above doesn't work, then use `config.getProperties()`, but I think it should be `getFeatures`.

Comment: I have `<init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>` in my web.xml, do I need to do this again?

Comment: You need it for the client, which I showed above. The error you are facing is a client error

Comment: You mean Google Api need this?

Comment: No I mean the Jersey `Client`

Comment: Woww I added this and it is working like a charm :)
Thank you so much :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125499/discussion-between-mdaniyal-and-peeskillet).